# RDS table opened in RStudio. How do I find field Names?

Tags: r, rds, field-names

As in the header, I have opened an RDS table in R Studio, and need to know the field names within that table.

But I don't know the correct command or syntax to follow this:

UK_2001 <- readRDS("D:/Census_History/Postcodes/2001_05_MAY_AFPD.rds")

Any guidance would be gratefully received.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `colnames(UK_2001)`?

Comment: Brilliant, very quick and perfect. Thanks Konrad!

Answer (score 0):

You can display the structure of any R object using `str` which will give you the object's type (e.g. data.frame), column names and column types as well.

`str(UK_2001)`

If you are just after the names of the columns `colnames` will do.